# Recuperar cidade a partir de id do banco de dados

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados

Estou pegando informações de um select, que puxa os estados e cidades cadastradas no banco de dados. No value de cada select (cidade e estado) está o id deles na tabela (somente deste jeito pra funcionar com a função em AJAX). Porém na hora de inserir não estou conseguindo transformar esse id do estado e da cidade no nome da cidade (`select * from cidade where id = $_post[cidade]`). Ao colocar um `mysqli_query` na variável PHP e depois tentar inseri-la dá um erro.

```
$cidade = $_POST['cidade'];
        $estado = $_POST['estado'];

        //Validando dados do formulário
        if(!empty($nome) && !empty($endereco)  && !empty($num) && !empty($CEP) && !empty($bairro) && !empty($cidade) && !empty($estado)){
            //Caso todos os campos sejam preenchidos, insere os valores na tabela estabelecimento
            mysqli_query($conectar, "INSERT INTO estabelecimento VALUES (NULL, '$nome', '$CNPJ', '$endereco',
            '$num', '$comp', '$CEP', '$bairro', '$cidade', '$estado', 0)");
```

[image: Estrutura da tabela]

Os dois primeiros registros foram inseridos manualmente no banco.

Comment: Qual é o erro que da? os dados são informações que você não digitou no formulário?

Comment: Na verdade está funcionando, mas eu só queria que inserisse o nome da cidade ao invés do id.

Answer (score 0):

Tem um erro na sua inserção:

Repare esse exemplo a sintaxe deve conter o nome dos campos que vai inserir,

```
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO pessoa ($FirstName,$LastName,$Age) 
VALUES ('Glenn','Quagmire',33)");
```

Outra coisa no caso de rotinas que precisa antes do **insert** efetuar um **select** você pode fazer assim :

```
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO pessoa ($FirstName,$LastName,$Age) 
SELECT 'Glenn','Quagmire',33 FROM pessoa WHERE id=12";
```

Isso evita o consumo de recursos do servidor porque minimiza o numero de queries, o **insert** e o **select** dentro da mesma consulta.

Ficaria assim o seu relacionamento entre entidades:

> SELECT * FROM estabelecimento e INNER JOIN cidades ON e.cod_cidade = cidades.id_cidade;

Ou seja :

> **SELECIONE TODOS OS CAMPOS DAS TABELAS ESTABELECIMENTO E CIDADES AONDE cod_cidade (conhecida como FK chave estrangeira de uma outra tabela) seja igual a id_cidade chave primaria da tabela cidades.**

Mesma coisa para a tabela estados....

Comment: Acho que você confundiu. O select a qual me refiro é um campo HTML

Comment: Sim eu me confundi! Mas a resposta ainda procede se você está coletando a id da cidade e do estado de seu formulário html e postando para essa rotina php vai receber os valores atáves da variavél global POST com isso basta efetuar o INSERT  com um select dentro coletando o nome da cidade e do estado selecionado e inserindo na nova tabela.

Comment: Um detalhe que costuma ser um pecodo contra a performance do sistema eu não aconselho guardar o nome da cidade e estado dentro da tabela estabelecimento. Nesse caso se guarda o id da cidade e estado, porque são chaves primarias das Tabelas. E portanto como são índíces toda a consulta que utilizar esses campos vão se agilizados por esse fato. Essa projeção que demonstrou vai causar um impacto de performance em seu sistema.

Comment: Então acredito que só armazenando os IDs resolveria meu problema (porque no final ele vai ficar do jeito que está). Assim teria que criar as relações com a tabela cidade e estado, correto?

Comment: Sim, quando necessitar efetuar o relacionamento entre a tabela de estabelecimento e a cidade ou estado bastaria construir uma query com join!

Comment: Alterei minha resposta confere! =P